# Simple nested for loop issue

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

While trying to implement nested for loops in a large dataframe, I realized that the nested for loops are not producing the results I expect. Here's an extract of my problem.

```
df <- data.frame(nrow = 20, ncol = 1)
df <- data.frame(  LastPrice = c( 1221, 1220, 1220, 1217, 1216,  1218 , 1216, 1216, 1217, 1220, 1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205))
for(j in 1:20) {for (i in 1:10) {df$SignalBinary[j] <- ifelse (df$LastPrice[j+i] == 1216, 1, 0)}}
```

I would expect and want the nested for loops to add SignalBinary vector to df dataframe with the following values: "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA"

- "1" on first 10 rows because 1216 is present for each in at least one of the 10 rows below
- "NA" on following 10 because for those the i loop extends outside the vector length

Instead, df$SignalBinary becomes
 "0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA"

Don't get it. Why is it registering only one 1216? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your first line for?  And also, what do you mean by *because 1216 is present for each in at least one of the 10 rows below*?  Below what?  Do you mean if 1216 is present in rows 11-20?

Comment: Guess first line not necessary. Meant present at least once in rows 02-11 for recording a 1 in row 1, at least once in rows 03-12 for recording a 1 in row 2 ... and at least once in rows 11-20 for recording a 1 in row 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to sum up in the second loop, so it only matches when the last one i is 2016. Try this:

```
for(j in 1:20) {
    tmp <- 0
    for (i in 1:10) 
        tmp <- tmp + ifelse(df$LastPrice[j+i] == 1216, 1, 0)
    df$SignalBinary[j] <- as.integer(tmp>0)
}
```

Or without a temp variable:

```
df$SignalBinary[j] <- 0
for(j in 1:20) {
    for(i in 1:10) 
        df$SignalBinary[j] <- as.integer(df$SignalBinary[j] || ifelse (df$LastPrice[j+i] == 1216, 1, 0));
        }
```

Comment: I'm humbled. Thank you!